# Jenkins windows service terminates unexpectedly while creating build through MSBuild and VSS

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, visual-sourcesafe

System Configuration:

Jenkins 1.533
MSBuild Plugin Version:1.20
VSS Plugin Version: 1.9
Visual Source Safe Version 8.0
Windows 7.0
Java 7
.Net 4.0

The Jenkins windows service crashes on the above configuration during the creation manual build. The issue occurs at a stage during the manual build process when the Console Output is displaying the message "[get] Getting source code from:[Project]". Please note that I 
have setup the MSBuild build file option to to the .sln file of my solution under the job configuration section.

Only log about the issue is windows event log which is provided below:

The windows event log related to this issue is written below:
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 7.0.400.43, time stamp: 0x521c3bf2
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdadb
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000c283b
Faulting process id: 0x10c8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cec01b7d599e70
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: b15a9788-2c10-11e3-baab-001cc0c11433

---

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: java.exe
P2: 7.0.400.43
P3: 521c3bf2
P4: StackHash_de94
P5: 6.1.7600.16385
P6: 4a5bdadb
P7: c0000374
P8: 000c283b
P9: 
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_java.exe_5fec1492735c7dda538ad3ac7e2393b22f3d4e_111af175

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: b15a9788-2c10-11e3-baab-001cc0c11433
Report Status: 4

---

Child process [4296 - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080] terminated with 255

=--------------------------------------------------------------

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: java.exe
P2: 7.0.400.43
P3: 521c3bf2
P4: StackHash_de94
P5: 6.1.7600.16385
P6: 4a5bdadb
P7: c0000374
P8: 000c283b
P9: 
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_java.exe_5fec1492735c7dda538ad3ac7e2393b22f3d4e_111af175

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: b15a9788-2c10-11e3-baab-001cc0c11433
Report Status: 0

Comment: "Visual Source Safe Version 8.0"  That thing still exists?

Comment: Yes it does and unfortunately being used in my company.

Comment: I would replace the "Get VSS source code" with a (temporary) "plain old copy command" (to get the source code from some network share or something)......and see if it still fails.  If not, then you know its VSS and can make a case to replace it.  Dude, that thing is a dinosaur........and your peer gruop of using jenkins with VSS is probably very very small.

Comment: the 1.9 version has a problem. try 1.8 instead.